# definition of decay process

Tags: particle-physics

Decay processes are quite common in particle physics.

Is the decay process always a $1 \rightarrow n$ process?

In other words, can we call the reaction $$\mu^{-} + \mu^{+} \rightarrow \phi,$$

where $\phi$ is some scalar particle, the decay of the muon?

Comment: Literally the first sentence of Wikipedia: "Particle decay is the spontaneous process of **one elementary particle** transforming into other elementary particles."

Comment: other elementary particles? So, the incoming particle cannot be in the set of outgoing particles?

Comment: Forbidden by conservation of energy. Easily seen by going to the rest frame of the decaying particle.

Comment: @user121664: That's not necessarily true. It requires the incoming particles to have an energy exactly that of the mass of the $\phi$, but that can happen. For example in finite temperature systems such as an expanding universe the bath of particles will have a range of energies including those required to make a $\phi$. Such processes will happen and may be very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Look at what happens](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2013/reviews/rpp2013-rev-cross-section-plots.pdf) with an easier reaction, e+ e- .

[image: e=e-]

fig 49.5

all these peaks are called resonances, and the ϕ is there.

ϕ  decays to e+e- and appears as a resonance in e+e- scattering.